# how to have a jquery function that runs both on load and on click

Tags: jquery, attributes, onclick, title, onload

how can i run a *jquery function* that runs both ***on load*** and ***on click***

```
$("#prevd,#nextd").live("click",function() {
alert('test');
$('#m0d1y2013').attr('title', 'New Year!');
$('#m0d21y2013').attr('title', 'Marthin Luthor King Day');
$('#m1d25y2013').attr('title', 'Presidents Day');
});
```

how can i run the contents of this jquery **without clicking** or setting up an ***on load click***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mySuperThings(){

   alert('test');
   $('#m0d1y2013').attr('title', 'New Year!');
   $('#m0d21y2013').attr('title', 'Marthin Luthor King Day');
   $('#m1d25y2013').attr('title', 'Presidents Day');

}

$(function(){              // DOM IS READY TO BE MANIPULATED

    mySuperThings();       // RUN FUNCTION

    $(document).on("click", "#prevd, #nextd", function() {
        mySuperThings();   // RUN ON CLICK
    });

});
```

P.S: taking in consideration you use jQuery *v.* >= 1.7 http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try raising a synthetic event using `.click()`.

```
$("#prevd,#nextd").live("click",function() {
  alert('test');
  ...
}).click();
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.7 you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event handler to dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  $(function(){
    $("#prevd,#nextd").live("click",function() {
      alert('test');
      $('#m0d1y2013').attr('title', 'New Year!');
      $('#m0d21y2013').attr('title', 'Marthin Luthor King Day');
      $('#m1d25y2013').attr('title', 'Presidents Day');
    });
    $(this).find("#prevd,#nextd").click();
  });
```